# What would be the optimal way to sort a long list of words in alphabetical order in C?

Tags: c, alphabetical-sort

As the title indicates, I need to order quite a few (hundreds of thousands) strings in alphabetical order. I have several linked lists and each linked list contains words of a specific length. That is, I have a 6 letter strings list, 7 letter strings list, ... , 10 letter strings list.

I was thinking of using radix sort, but I wanted to see if there were better options out there since I can't find anything specific when it comes to alphabetizing a list where all the words are the same length.

EDIT:

I have an extremely long list of words, raging in size. I'm currently walking through the list and arranging the words into size categories. That is, when I encounter a word of length 6 it goes into the "6-length" list. As I'm doing this for each word, I am actually creating a new word object that contains the original word and its alphabetized version (e.g. stack, ackst). I want to alphabetize each "length" list such that I could easily find and group anagrams.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the fact that the lengths are the same matters to sorting, does it? You don't explain how you think that would affect sorting.

My recommended approach for sorting a linked list: don't. :) Sort an array instead, and convert to/from the linked list as needed. It will very likely be much faster and easier.

Basically:

1. Walk the list to figure out the length.
2. Allocate an array of value pointers (in your case, "value" means string).
3. Walk the list again, setting the i:th array element to point to the i:th list item's data.
4. Sort the array with `qsort()`.
5. Walk the list a third time, overwriting the i:th item's data with the i:th array element
6. Done.

You can do this for each linked list separately, of course.

Comment: Please see my edit above. As for the sorting length, I noticed that most radix sort implementations first check for the longest number/string they would have to deal with and I don't need to do that. I need to write my own sorting algorithm from scratch, I can't use pre-built sorts.

Comment: @Michi I'm sorry, it's still not very clear to me. Why do you need the "alphabetized version" of each string? How does that affect sorting? Why do you *need* to write your own *sorting algorithm*?

Comment: for his homework dude ^^ by the way nice approach unwind

Comment: @Michi: If this is homework, then that's a pretty cruel assignment. Write 'the optimal way' to sort strings (and do so in C, of all languages)... Your teacher just sent you off to look for the holy grail. Study this, then tell me which algorithm is 'the optimal way': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Efficient_sorts

Comment: @unwind The goal of this project is to create "anagram classes", which means each class will contain all words that are anagrams of one another. What I'm doing is alphabetizing each string such that I would have a simple key that would be used for determining whether this word and another word are anagrams of one another as the alphabetized version of anagrams should be identical. Thus, once I have lists sorted alphabetically by those keys, all I will have to do is compare a key to the next key in the list to see if two words are anagrams.

Comment: @unwind Yes, this is homework and it's very reasonable in my opinion as it is for my algorithms course. I chose to do this in C because Python has been giving me heap overflow errors because there are so many words (6mil) that need to be grouped by their anagram class. I am graded based on my running time and computational complexity. Since I don't need this to be comparison based if I'm sorting by keys, I thought radix sort would work best but I wanted to see other opinions.